# Error auth using soap-node

Tags: node.js, web-services, soap

I have a problem with [soap-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap), my header have auth:

XML-service SOAP

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <Autentication xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <Pass>string</Pass>
      <Us>string</Us>
    </Autentication>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <getdata xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" />
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

App.js - Node.js

```
var soap = require('soap');
var url = "http://localhost/abc/example.asmx?WSDL"

var Autentication = {
  "Autentication": {
    "Pass" : "david",
  "Us" : "hackro"
  }
}
var args = {}

soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
  if(err)return console.log(err)

      client.addSoapHeader(Autenticacion)

      client.ObtieneKey(args, function(err, result,body) {
          if(err) return console.log(body)

            console.log(result);
            console.log(body);
    })
})
```

But my auth fail because return empty

```
{ data: "" }
```

I see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30951264/3741698) but it doesn't work.

Comment: We try to discourage the phrase "doesn't work" here, since it is not a clear statement of a problem. Can you edit your question to expand on that at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem sending my header in this way

```
var Autentication ='<Autentication xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">Pass>david</Pass><Us>hackro</Us>/Autentication></soap:Header>'
```

Add header

```
client.addSoapHeader(Autentication)
```

**Good Luck**